General solution of the wave equation using Laplace transform in the time domain
I have been exploring different methods of solving PDEs and in general various solutions of the wave equation under more general boundary conditions (like if the boundaries are ($-\infty$, $\infty$) or something like $(0, \infty)$) and also under more relaxed conditions for the solutions (like non-square integrability so that solutions like the exponential traveling wave: $e^{a(x-ct)}$ are possible).
I face an issue in trying to derive such general solutions of the wave equation, starting out with taking a Laplace transform in the time domain and, proceeding to solve the ODE in the space domain, finally concluding with an inverse Laplace transform to the time domain.
Consider:
$$ u_{tt} = c^2u_{xx} \\  x \in \mathbb{R}, t>0 \\ u(x,0)=f(x); u_t(x,0)=g(x)$$
I start by taking a Laplace transform in the time-domain so that
$$ s^2U(x, s) - su(x, 0) - u_t(x,0) = c^2U_{xx}(x,s) $$
where, $U(x,s)$ is the Laplace transform of $u(x,t)$.
Now the solution of this ODE in $x$ can be given as:
$$ U(x,s) = H(x, s) + P(x, s) \\ H(x, s) = A(s)e^{\frac{s}{c}x} + B(s)e^{-\frac{s}{c}x} \rightarrow \text{Homogeneous Solution} \\ \text{ and } \bigg (\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} - \frac{s^2}{c^2}\bigg)P(x,s) = -\frac{s}{c}u(x,0) - \frac{1}{c}u_t(x,0) \rightarrow \text{Inhomogeneous Solution}$$
$P(x,s)$ must be computed based on $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.
Moving on, taking the Inverse Laplace transform:
$$ u(x,t) = \int_{\sigma -j\infty}^{\sigma +j\infty} [ A(s)e^{\frac{s}{c}x} + B(s)e^{-\frac{s}{c}x} ]e^{st} + P(x,s)e^{st} ds \\ \implies u(x,t) = \int_{\sigma -j\infty}^{\sigma +j\infty} [ A(s)e^{\frac{s}{c}(x+ct)} + B(s)e^{-\frac{s}{c}(x-ct)} ] + P(x,s)e^{st} ds$$
The first part of this integral makes sense; it's essentially a superposition of every possible left and right-moving travelling waves, and these are not restricted to just sinusoids but also contain decaying and exponentially growing waves. It makes sense; I expect such a solution because I have not put restrictions such as those put by the Fourier transform, which requires square-integrability and thus finite energy, ultimately reducing the solution space to just traveling sinusoids. This also reconciles with D'Alembert's general solution to the wave equation: $ u(x,t) = F(x-ct) + G(x+ct)$.
The issue is the second part of the integral. How do I make sure that the inverse Laplace transform of $P(x,s)$ will always be of the type: $F(x-ct) + G(x+ct)$
The only useful thing I can think of is that it must be related to the constraint that $P(x,s)$ must satisfy the inhomogeneous ODE and that in order for Laplace transform to work as a whole $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ must be exponentially bounded i.e $abs(f(x)) \text{ and } abs(g(x)) < Me^{Nx}$.
Insights or solutions will be appreciated.

A useful question.
